# Finding chronological age on Filemaker to be used in equation

Tags: filemaker

I'm trying to calculate a chronological age based on a person's birth date (DOB) and the date of evaluation (DOE). I need the answer to be expressed as a numerical number that can be put in an equation. For example if a person's DOB is 12/26/07 and the DOE is 10/13/15 the chronological age will be 7.75, NOT 7;9 (7 years, 9 months). The decimal place needs to be a function out of 12, not simply representing the age in months. I have accurately calculated this but every time the chronological age is configured to be an even age (9 years 0 months) the calculation shows up as 90, I really need this "90" to be a "9.0" is there anything I can do to configure this into my calculation? The current calculation that is working for every other age is:

Year ( GetAsNumber ( DOE )) - Year ( DOB ) - If ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) < Date ( Month ( DOB ) ; Day ( DOB ) ; Year ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) ) ); 1 ; 0 ) & ( Mod ( Month ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) ) - Month ( DOB ) + 12 - If ( Day ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) ) < Day ( DOB ) ; 1 ; 0 ) ; 12 ) / 12)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your Calculation is ok, but you are concatenating the 2 parts rather than adding them. That's why you get a "90" instead of a "9"

Also, if you want it to be "9.0", the calculation result must be numeric; and in layout mode set the format to decimal with a fixed number of decimals.

```
Round (
    Year ( GetAsNumber ( DOE )) - Year ( DOB ) -
    If (
        GetAsNumber ( DOE ) < Date ( Month ( DOB ) ; Day ( DOB ) ; Year ( GetAsNumber ( DOE )));
        1 ;
        0)
    +
    ( Mod ( 
        Month ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) ) - Month ( DOB ) + 12 -
            If (
                Day ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) ) < Day ( DOB );
                1;
                0)
        ; 12 )
    / 12)
 ; 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler approach:

```
Let ( 
elapsedMonths = 12 * ( Year ( DOE ) - Year ( DOB ) ) + Month ( DOE ) - Month ( DOB ) - ( Day ( DOE ) < Day ( DOB ) ) 
;
Div ( elapsedMonths ; 12 ) + Mod ( elapsedMonths ; 12 ) / 12
)
```

Note that this counts only *fully* elapsed months.